# How do I can call event from usercontrol to main form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

I have a userControl and I've a button there, I'd like to call event when I'm clicking on the button in my main form from userControl. I do this:

UserControl

```
public UserControlerConstructor()
{
    _button.Click += new EventHandler(OnButtonClicked);
}

public delegate void ButtonClickedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ButtonClickedEventHandler OnUserControlButtonClicked;

private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Delegate the event to the caller
    if (OnUserControlButtonClicked != null)
        OnUserControlButtonClicked(this, e);
}
```

Form

```
public Form1()
{            
    userControlInstance.OnUserControlButtonClicked += new EventHandler(OnUCButtonClicked);
}

private void OnUCButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

It doesn't work because when I click in the form do nothing in the form code, but it does in userControl code. But I'd like to do in form code. I don't know how to call event from userControl to the form.

Comment: The question is not much clear, but what I understand is you are asking to call the event of user control in form control. It is a restriction in events that only owning class can tell when to where to call an event. You can only register event handlers in subscribing classes.

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you using a custom delegate? You can just make it `public event EventHandler OnUserControlButtonClicked`

Comment: Yes, the compiler doesn't halt it.

Comment: @Fildor you're right, bad choice of word. :)

Comment: your code doesn't compile: `EventHandler` cannot be converted to `ButtonClickedEventHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Well now I don't know if you're explicity want to use the delegate, no? If not, why don't you just do:

```
public Form1()
    {            
        userControlInstance._button.Click += OnUCButtonClicked;
    }

private void OnUCButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

up to now your code does not compile. You are using the wrong event handler type. It should show the following compiler error:

> EventHandler cannot be converted to ButtonClickedEventHandler

Do the following steps:

1) put the declaration of the delegate outside of the class `UserControlerConstructor`:

```
public delegate void ButtonClickedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public partial class UserControlerConstructor: UserControl
{
```

1) then change the type of the handler when registering the event in `Form`:

```
public Form1()
{            
    userControlInstance.OnUserControlButtonClicked += new ButtonClickedEventHandler(OnUCButtonClicked);
}
```

This way it should work